# How can non-admin monitor GPFS i/o

Tags: linux, networking, suse, non-admin

Running on SuSE, I am one of several "uninitiated" users on a moderately sized cluster farm. I have my suspicions that something is not right with i/o to the mounted /home. How can I get some data on this *without* asking the admin?

Comment: would /var/log/gpfs/iohist.log be useful?

Comment: Oh boy, that's an old question isn't it.
Also, /var/log/gpfs does not exist, probably because we have moved on to RHEL.
What we have done since is to hook up everything to http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/